# Google analytics syntax event label and or results don't match

Tags: google-analytics

I am new to querying GA with event label filters and am trying to work out my mistake with the following syntax.  I have 3 different event label filters on 3 separate reports which are identical, except for the variation in this query:

Report filter 1: `ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2`

Report filter 2: `ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;ga:eventLabel!=Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query`

Report filter 3: `ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;ga:eventLabel==Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query`

Now, I would expect that the count of sessions and users I get from report filter #1 would equal the sum of results from report filters #2 and #3.   But actually, report filter #2: `ga:eventLabel==Login - Create Account Step 2;ga:eventLabel!=Where to Buy Step 2 Submit Query` returns counts of users and sessions orders of magnitude larger than the other 2 queries.  (like 70K vs 120ish).  Feels like there's a classic beginner conceptual error I'm making here, but I'm not sure how to google the the right question.  Any ideas what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks for any help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are trying to query with session/user metrics won't really work the reason being is that events are hits and so filtering that way filters on the hits. The way to get around that is to create segments of users that have triggered the events that you are interested in.

Now if you were to report on events/unique events using those filters based on the logic there I would expect #1 and #2 to return the same results and #3 to contain no values.

Comment: I believe this is the correct answer.  Thanks!  I'll try using the ga syntax to qualify my filters for users like users::condition::ga:eventLabel etc.